# v8.0.0-beta.2 - Error: src/main/webapp/app/core/util/data-util.service.ts:4:24 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'buffer'

Tags: jhipster

I upgraded to jhipster v8.0.0-beta.2
I create a project using a jdl file with a config{...}

I get the following error.

```
    [jhipster] Error: src/main/webapp/app/core/util/data-util.service.ts:4:24 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'buffer'. 'node_modules/buffer/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

Comment: What version of Node are you using? Can you try with Node 18?

Comment: ❯ node -v
v18.16.1